# Права для скрипта

Tags: python, apache, linux

Скрипт из под апача пытается писать в файл и получает ошибку: не прав на запись.

```
f = open('/var/www', 'w')print f
```

Какие права и куда надо добавить?

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod 755 -R /var/www
```

Не уверен, что то что вы делаете, вообще осуществимо (вы пытаетесь прочесть директорию? что это за команда?)

Answer (score 0):

На тот файл, в который пытаешься записать, выставь права.

```
cmod +x /путь/к/файлу/название.файла
```

Может так поможет.